# Adding a user control to a page programatically while preserving controls already present

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, runtime

I am trying to add a user control into a div at runtime. I can add the control no probelem but it overwrites the previous control added.

Basically, I am trying to add passengers to a travel system - the passenger details are in the user control and I don't know in advance how many there will be. I have an add new passenger button which should append the new user control into the div without overwriting the previous passenger.

The code is c#/.net 4.

I have tried to save the control data into viewstate and re add it with the new one but that also doesn't work. Here is a snippet of the code I'm using

```
foreach (Control uc in p_passengers.Controls) {
        Passenger p = uc as Passenger;
        if (p != null) {
            p.SaveValues();            
        }
    }
```

however, p.SaveAs() (just writes the control values into ViewState) is never hit.

Im sure its just something stupid but any ideas??

Cheers guys.

Comment: How and when do you add that control?

Comment: Which page event are you doing this in, Init, Load, PreRender?

Comment: I'm adding the control in the click handler of a link button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you [re-creating all of your dynamic controls for every postback](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)?

Remember each postback is a new instance of the Page class and any controls you previously created will need to be explicitly re-created.

**Update**

If you had a list of added items in viewstate, something like this..

```
    private List<string> Items
    {
         get
         {
              return ViewState["Items"] = (ViewState["Items"] ?? new List<string>());
         }
    }
```

Then in your click handler you could simply add to this list :

```
   private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        this.Items.Add("Another Item");
   }
```

Then override [CreateChildControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.createchildcontrols.aspx)

```
  protected overrides CreateChildControls()
  {
       foreach (string item in this.Items)
       {
            Passanger p = new Passenger();
            p.Something = item;
            this.p_passengers.Controls.Add(p);
       }
  }
```

Comment: I think this is kind of what im trying to do with the SaveValues method. I could persist the control into viewstate but the line in the foreach never gets hit. I saw someone do foreach(UserControl...) but that gave me cast exceptions.

Comment: re: update - This looks pretty much exactly what I am trying to do. I read that article but was struggling to put two and two together. I need it to recreate the viewstate for the added controls (user data might not be persisted at this stage), could I stash the whole passenger object in the viewstate or is that a bit much?

Comment: Fixed! @RichardFriend, Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It was down to not recreating the controls. I had to do something a little different and ended up using this control which can persist the dynamic elements and viewstate automagically:
[link](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx)