# Dynamic creation of Button OK but its event handler NOT executed?

Tags: asp.net

I have following simple controls on a page

`WebForm1.aspx`

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

Some code behind in `WebForm1.aspx.cs` :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "btnTest";
    btn.Text = "I was dynamically created";
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnTest_Click);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
}

void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblContent.Text = "btnTest_Click: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

In short, when I dynamically create a Button (`btnTest`) in the `Page_Load` event and assign event handler `btnTest_Click` to the button. Click event then, when loading the page I see `btnTest` appearing and when clicking on it the event handler `btnTest_Click` is invoked. OK,  No problem.

I have a problem though when I try following scenario... first, I add a button to the page in designer mode.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button     ID="btnCreateDynamically" runat="server" 
            Text="Create Button Dynamically" 
                onclick="btnCreateDynamically_Click" />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblContent" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
```

I move the code from `Page_Load` to the button event handler of `btnCreateDynamically` as follows

```
protected void btnCreateDynamically_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "btnTest";
    btn.Text = "I was dynamically created";
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnTest_Click);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

When running the WebApp now and clicking on `btnCreateDynamically`, btnTest is created but when I click on `btnTest`  its event handler is NOT invoked ???

Why not?
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

You should add the dynamic controls in the Page's Init event handler so that the ViewState and Events are triggered appropriately.

Try doing this:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{         
    Button btn = new Button();         
    btn.ID = "btnTest";         
    btn.Text = "I was dynamically created";         
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnTest_Click);         
    Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);     
}
```

Comment: What if the controls are to be added on a click event as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338798/eventhandler-is-not-working-for-dynamic-control ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [re-create dynamic control on each postback](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx), see my previous answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434521/adding-a-user-control-to-a-page-programatically-while-preserving-controls-already/5434572#5434572)